# Set Cookie value when link is clicked in Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

In a NET Core 7 using Razor Pages I have a HeaderViewComponent:

```
public class HeaderViewComponent : ViewComponent {

  public HeaderViewComponent() { }

  public IViewComponentResult Invoke() {
    return View();
  }

}
```

Where part of the HTML is:

```
 <ul>           
   @foreach (String culture in cultures) {
     <li>
       <a href='@Url.RouteUrl(new RouteValueDictionary { { "culture", @culture } })'>@culture</a>
     </li>
   }         
</ul>
```

I have this View Component in all my Razor Pages.

When one of the links is clicked I want more than redirect.

I also need to set the value of a cookie named "Culture".

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you set the cookie when serving the endpoint that's being redirected _to_?

Comment: I am redirecting to the same razor page but with route culture parameter defined. But I only want to set culture cookie when I click the link because that mens the Cookie Value must change.

Comment: override `<a>` href action and using js to change cookie? `document.cookie = "username=John Doe";`